# Programming Language for Mac OS X application

Tags: c++, macos

I have an upcoming project coming up in which I want to dedicate several months to making a professional application which is basically a text editor with a special purpose (can't disclose too many details). The program shouldn't be too complicated, but I wanted it to have a nice GUI and be fast enough to sell from either the Mac App store or my website.

I was going to initially make it for Mac OS X and then later Windows and I wanted to know, for someone who is intermediate at programming, what language should I use for this program? Should I use a library? I already have a foundation in c++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The Language

Well, if you have a solid foundation in C++, by all means use C++! However, I must warn you that C++ has a bad reputation for allowing only those people to use it who know *every damn feature of the language*. Therefore, you may soon run into problems if you don't have a thorough knowledge of templates for instance.

With reference to the platform, in my opinion, all mainstream languages are more-or-less good enough for Mac OS X development ( or Windows development ), it really depends on what you feel convenient using.

### The Library

Now we come to my favourite part. Comparing Application frameworks. There are many choices when using Mac OS X. If you want to target multiple platforms ( as  you say, you want to also support Windows later on), I suggest [GTK+](http://www.gtk.org/) or [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/products/). For a comparison between the two libraries, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9441127/gui-development-qt-vs-gtk/9443796#9443796).

Answer (score 2):

The standard programming language for Mac OS X is Objective-C, however, as a rock solid Unix descendant, it also has great C and C++ support. If you want to write an efficient, nice and native (OS X) look-and-feel GUI, I'd suggest you use Cocoa (it has Objective-C interfaces) which is Apple's default and official GUI implementation for OS X. Considering portabilitiy, however, you may also use some cross platform GUI/widget toolkit, such as QT, GTK+, etc. (which are also, in general, written in C/C++).

Answer (score 1):

If you're programming for OS X, check out [Cocoa](https://developer.apple.com/technologies/mac/cocoa.html). If you're aiming to create multi-platform applications, check out [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/).

Cocoa uses Objective-C, which is a superset of C - transitioning to it from C++ isn't too difficult, and the [Apple Developers site](http://developer.apple.com) has quite a bit of information for beginners.

Qt works with C++ or Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can use marmelade

http://www.madewithmarmalade.com/

To make your application portable and you can write it in C language.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Free Pascal with Lazarus for this, with native interface (still Carbon on OS X though, the Cocoa interface is still in development AFAIK) due to its natural cross platform behavior, both language and libraries so there's no external dependencies required. This would require you to learn another language and framework (it's the same with C++ if you're planning to use QT, GTK, or whatever you've never used before) however.